Upload button not working when submitting the files to merge
I am trying to make a PDF merger using Bootstrap and Express. The upload button is not working after clicking on it, it throws some error. What to do to make it right?
Here is the link to my repo
After clicking on upload button it showing me this error

Assuming your server accepts POST requests, I think that this question may help you.

Check your server logs for any more detailed error messages that might provide clues about the problem.
Make sure that your server is configured to handle file uploads correctly. This may involve setting up the appropriate middleware or configuring your web framework to handle multipart form data.
Try using a different browser or device to upload the file. This can help to rule out any issues with your local environment.
